# Getting the error "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named Flask" in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, mongodb, aws-lambda, flask-restful

Upon trying to run my code on AWS Lambda, I am getting the error "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named Flask"

I have already installed python and python flask in the virtual environment and all other required libraries

```
import Flask
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'users'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://127.0.:27017/users'

mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/user', methods=['POST'])
def get_userdetail():
    user = mongo.db.users
    output = []

    for s in user.find():
        output.append({'Firstname' : s['Firstname'], 'Lastname' : 
                       s['Lastname']})
    return jsonify({'result' : output})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I just expected the code to run but instead I am getting this error

Comment: "I have already installed python and python flask in the virtual environment..." What virtual environment? Lambda requires you to [add your dependencies directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#python-package-dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

You need first to do some steps, so the dependencies will be installed automatically when you deploy to AWS Lambda. For example to use "serverless-python-requirements" to install the requriments.txt file. For more details, you can check this: https://medium.com/@Twistacz/flask-serverless-api-in-aws-lambda-the-easy-way-a445a8805028

I also noticed that your MONGO_URI is pointing to your local folder, and that's will not work when you deploy online. Check how to make a config file with two classes, one for production and one for development. So when you deploy, you just change to Production.

I hope that will help.

Comment: So, for the MONGO_URI, should I enter the ip address where my MongoDB is hosted?

Comment: So if you have the MONGO db on AWS, then go to AWS console and get the URL. Check this link : https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/